# How to set URL in range A1 in a specific sheet as variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Googlesheet Script
I want to use the Googlesheet script code to extract data from NSE Link on dailybasis. The URL changes on daily basis and i want to automate it.

https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2019/JAN/cm25JAN2019bhav.csv.zip

the date in the URL (25JAN2019) changes on daily basis. I get the updated URL in cell A1 of Sheet called 'T-3'. Now I want to know how can I put the same in script

I tried using the following 3 codes, but it is not working

1

```
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('T-3').getRange("A1").getvalue();
```

2

```
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('T-3').getRange('A1').getvalue();
```

3

```
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('T-3').getRange(1,1).getvalue();
```

The following is the working code

```
function myFunction1() {
var url = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2019/JAN/cm25JAN2019bhav.csv.zip" 
var zipblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob(); 
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob); 
var unzipstr=unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(unzipstr);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('T-1');
ss.getRange(2, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a typo, use getValue() instead of getvalue()?

```
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('T-3').getRange("A1").getValue();
```

Comment: Thank you Niek. Was searching the correct code since very long time. Thanks a ton.